# get, Json if the status is OK, go to url

Tags: angularjs, json, response

I have the following controller

```
angular    
.module('MyApp')
.controller('CtrlName', CtrlName);

function CtrlName($scope, $http){
    $http.get('https://url.myService.com/SpecificService'  }).success(function(data) {
    $location.path('/desiredState/');
    $scope.CtrlName = data;
    });
}
```

I want to redirect to a another **state** if the status (into the response) is OK. If is fail, go to another state

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.success`, you can use the  `.then` function.

It accepts two functions as arguments. The first is for a successful callback, the second is for an error. You can use the second callback to navigate the user to another state.

```
function CtrlName($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('https://url.myService.com/SpecificService')
         .then(function(data) {
             $location.path('/desiredState/');
             $scope.CtrlName = data;
         }, function(data) {
             // go to error
      });
}
```